# more_like_this is not working for repeated same text in field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6, morelikethis

We are using elasticsearch 6.0 to find out similar components in the elasticsearch index. we are using **more_like_this** for that. the repeated text in the field is not given proper result

1) 1st component field have text like this:

> **fan fan fan in the room**

2) 2nd component field have text like this:

> one two three **fan fan fan in the room**.

when I try to find out similar components like 1st components, then elk is not showing any result.

How I can get elasticsearch result which will work for repeated text as well as a unique word in the field.

**Note:-We will not able to add min_term_freq.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default min_doc_freq is 5, So your query is not working because your index doesn't contain at least 5 documents whose term property holds yellow. So, set min_doc_freq to 1 in your query and it should work.

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
            "like": "Hello",
            "min_term_freq": 1,
            "min_doc_freq": 1
        }
    }
}
```

For reference we can go [Elasticsearch More Like this no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236844/elasticsearch-more-like-this-no-result)

Comment: https://qbox.io/blog/mlt-similar-documents-in-elasticsearch-more-like-this-query please go through this perfect reference for more like this